# script to check script is running and start it, if it’s stopped

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a script with this name : Run.sh

I run this script with this command :

```
./run.sh
```

I don't like stop this script but this script Suddenly stops and need run again.

I need a script to check it , if my run.sh stopped , run it again.

this is run.sh codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


install() {
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get upgrade
}

if [ "$1" = "install" ]; then
  install
  else

if [ ! -f ./tg/tgcli ]; then
    echo "tg not found"
    echo "Run $0 install"
    exit 1
 fi

   #sudo service redis-server restart
   #./tg/tgcli -s ./bot/bot.lua -l 1 -E $@
   ./tg/tgcli -s ./bot/bot.lua $@
fi
```

And i want run this script at boot (with screen or tmux) if my server restart

i have Ubuntu 16.04 version

Thank you Ljm Dullaart

Can you help me about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need to run the complete bash script again. Changing

```
./tg/tgcli -s ./bot/bot.lua $@
```

to

```
while :; do
   ./tg/tgcli -s ./bot/bot.lua $@
done
```

will restart bot.lua  everytime it exits.

Comment: can you help me to run it at boot ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your run.sh is running and re-run it if stopped with a single command:

```
$ if ! pgrep run.sh ;then /path/to/run.sh;fi
```

If script runs pgrep will return exit status 0 = success and will print the pid of run.sh
If script does not run pgrep will return exit status 1 and then script will be called.

You can also use `pgrep inst.sh >/dev/null` to "mute" pgrep in case script is running.

Comment: thank you but i need always check ! can you help me to run my script at boot ?